# Live search input TEXT to URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

It is my my first time trying to send INPUT text to URL and ALL i want is that when i search something like "cleveland". It will go as `index.php?searchText=cleveland` IN the URL.

But the output in the URL is:
`index.php?searchText=c?searchText=cl?searchText=cle?searchText=clev?searchText=cleve?searchText=clevel?searchText=clevela?searchText=clevelan?searchText=cleveland`.

I can't find any solutions online so i hope someone can explain this to me on how to fix this.

AJAX code:

```
function searchFilterInput(page_number) {
  page_number = page_number?page_number:0;
  var search = $('#search').val();
  var getUrl = window.location;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getData.php',
    data:'page='+page_number+'&search='+search,
    success: function (data) {
// Below doesn't work like it should</b>
    window.history.replaceState("object or string", "Page Title", getUrl+"?searchText="+keywords);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's being called on each keypress, and you're not removing/ignoring the previous query string from the URL before adding the new one.

Comment: Use `var getUrl = window.location.origin;` instead of `var getUrl = window.location;`

Comment: @DBS Thanks for your time. Can you make a answer please i am a beginner on this stuff.

Comment: @hoangdv Thanks for your time. I don't know what the difference is now but i will test it now. Thanks

Comment: @DBS I am still searching but i can't seem to solve it can you help me please

Comment: @hoangdv Can you help me i can't figure it out.

Comment: @DBS Can you help me i can't figure it out.

Comment: @DBS How can i remove ignore the previous query. Been searching for hours

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use ajax for that, in fact you do not even need javascript to do that.

```
<form method="GET" action="index.php">
  <input type="text" name="searchText"/>
  <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have a live search input field so i don't press a button and it needs to be done without reloading the page. Will your method still work?

Comment: I tested it and oke this works great but how to do it with LIVE search? And also without reloading.

Comment: I am still searching but i can't seem to solve it can you help me please

Comment: Can you help me i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for people searching it here you go:

```
$("#keywords").keyup(function () {
  var keywords = $('#keywords').val(); //searchInput
var pathname = "?searchText="+keywords;
history.pushState({}, '', 'products.html'+pathname);
});
```

Comment: It was'nt clear to me from your Questuion that you need to do it without reloading. `pushState()` is the way to go then. But keep in mind that with that code you will clutter your browser history as you push a new history on every keypress. You might want to use the `change` event instead of the `keyup` event to avoid that.